# Java Spring conexion con wamp. No me inserta el registro

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-tool-suite

estoy aprendiendo el **Framework Spring de Java** y siguiendo un tutorial hice unas **clases** con los repsectivos atributos que coincidieran con los que tengo montado en la base de datos. Y lo que pretendo es **insertar los datos en la Base de datos de mi WAMP Server**

Tengo 4 paquetes principales:

- beans
- dao
- service
- main

**Paquete Beans**

```
    public class Camiseta {

        private int id;
        private int numero;
        private Marca marca;

        public int getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public void setId(int id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        public int getNumero() {
            return numero;
        }

        public void setNumero(int numero) {
            this.numero = numero;
        }

        public Marca getMarca() {
            return marca;
        }

        public void setMarca(Marca marca) {
            this.marca = marca;
        }

    }






    public class Equipo {

        private int id;
        private String nombre;

        public int getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public void setId(int id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        public String getNombre() {
            return nombre;
        }

        public void setNombre(String nombre) {
            this.nombre = nombre;
        }

    }




public class Jugador {

    private int id;
    private String nombre;
    private Equipo equipo;
    private Camiseta camiseta;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    public Equipo getEquipo() {
        return equipo;
    }

    public void setEquipo(Equipo equipo) {
        this.equipo = equipo;
    }

    public Camiseta getCamiseta() {
        return camiseta;
    }

    public void setCamiseta(Camiseta camiseta) {
        this.camiseta = camiseta;
    }

}



public class Marca {

    private int id;
    private String nombre;



    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

}
```

**Paquete dao**

```
import com.mitocode.beans.Marca;

public interface DAOMarca {

    public void registrar(Marca marca) throws Exception;
}



import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.mitocode.beans.Marca;


@Repository //estereotipo de una determinada capa
public  class DAOMarcaImpl implements DAOMarca {

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;


    public void registrar(Marca marca) throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        String sql = "INSERT INTO marca(marca_id, marca_nombre) VALUES (?,?)";
        Connection con = null;
        try {
            con =  dataSource.getConnection();
            PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
            ps.setInt(1, marca.getId());
            ps.setString(2, marca.getNombre());
            ps.executeUpdate();
            ps.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }
        finally {
            if (con != null) {
                con.close();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

**Paquete service**

```
import com.mitocode.beans.Marca;

public interface ServiceMarca {
    public void registrar(Marca marca) throws Exception;

}


import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.mitocode.beans.Marca;
import com.mitocode.dao.DAOMarca;

@Service
public class ServiceMarcaImpl implements ServiceMarca {

private DAOMarca daoMarca;

    public void registrar(Marca marca) throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try {
            daoMarca.registrar(marca);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }
        finally {

        }
    }

}
```

**Paquete main**

```
Marca marca = new Marca();
marca.setId(666);
marca.setNombre("Mi marca");


ApplicationContext appContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("com/mitocode/xml/beans.xml");

ServiceMarca sm = (ServiceMarca) appContext.getBean("serviceMarcaImpl");


try {
    sm.registrar(marca);
} catch (Exception e) {
    // TODO: handle exception
    System.out.println("Error insercion: "+e);
}
```

**beans.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.2.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.mitocode"></context:component-scan>


    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"></property>
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db_spring"></property>
        <property name="username" value="root"></property>
        <property name="password" value=""></property>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

**pom.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.mitocode</groupId>
    <artifactId>springbd</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>springbd</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.37</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
</project>
```

[image: Estructura de la Base de datos]

Mi **problema** surge a la hora de insertar en la base de datos que no lo hace y no se porque.
Añadir tambien  que no me da error en ningun momento. Tanto en las estrucutras xml como ala hora de llamar al metodo que inserta la marca en el main cerrado en try catch.

---

He encontrado nueva informacion acerca de mi error. En la clase `ServiceMarca.java` me da una excepcion `java.lang.NullPointerException`

Comment: "no me da error en ningun momento" Posiblemente porque **estás ignorando cualquier excepción que te salga**, al comerte las excepciones con `} catch (Exception e) {            // TODO: handle exception  }`. Haz log o imprime las excepciones para saber qué está pasando.

Comment: Si hago el log con el SOUT pero no me sale nada de errores eso es a lo que me refiero, pero miro en la base de datos y no me inserta. No se si hay que tenener en cuenta algo especial a la hora de trabajar con **Spring + WAMP**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te escribo en respuesta porque no me deja añadir comentario. Has mirado que el fichero application.properties tenga bien configurado el datasource? Creo que no te esta haciendo bien la conexión a la base de datos por eso.
El fichero application.properties esta dentro de resources.

---

Edit: Pienso que falla algo en conectarte a la base de datos. Prueba a conectarte de la siguiente manera:

```
DataSource ds = (DataSource)ApplicationContextProvider.getApplicationContext().getBean("dataSource");
Connection c = ds.getConnection();
```

---

Edit: Disculpa; Tienes que declarar un ApplicationContext de la siguiente manera, en el Paquete dao:

```
@Autowired
private ApplicationContext appContext;
```

Luego hacer la conexión de la siguiente manera:

```
DataSource ds = (DataSource)appContext.getBean("dataSource");
Connection c = ds.getConnection();
```

El paquete dao quedaría así:

```
import com.mitocode.beans.Marca;

public interface DAOMarca {

    public void registrar(Marca marca) throws Exception;
}



import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.mitocode.beans.Marca;


@Repository //estereotipo de una determinada capa
public  class DAOMarcaImpl implements DAOMarca {

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext appContext;

private DataSource ds;


    public void registrar(Marca marca) throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        String sql = "INSERT INTO marca(marca_id, marca_nombre) VALUES (?,?)";
        Connection con = null;
        try {
ds=(DataSource)appContext.getBean("dataSource");
            con =  ds.getConnection();
            PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
            ps.setInt(1, marca.getId());
            ps.setString(2, marca.getNombre());
            ps.executeUpdate();
            ps.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }
        finally {
            if (con != null) {
                con.close();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

---

Añado nueva informacion descubierta:

Me da `Error 'Service Marca': java.lang.NullPointerException` en la clase `ServiceMarca.java`

---

Creo que ya sé que es. Era algo más simple que todo eso.

Modifica la clase ServiceMarcaImpl tal que así:

```
@Service
public class ServiceMarcaImpl implements ServiceMarca {

@Autowired
private DAOMarcaImpl daoMarca;

    public void registrar(Marca marca) throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try {
            daoMarca.registrar(marca);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }
        finally {

        }
    }

}
```

Pasa porque estas creando un objeto de una interface en vez de su implementación.

Comment: no me reconoce `ApplicationContextProvider`

Comment: Prueba lo que puse, a ver si es eso.

Comment: sigue sin insertarlo en la BD, no entiendo porque

Comment: @josanangel Te ha servido la última edición? Por cierto, que paquete dao has usado, el que puse yo en la edición o el que tu pusiste en tu mensaje principal?

Comment: me di cuenta que lo que me esta arrojando es un error de nullpointerException

Comment: los dos los he probado

Comment: Modifica la clase ServiceMarcaImpl tal como te indique en mi respuesta. Estoy casi seguro que es eso.

Comment: eso era, perfecto !! El problema era que no tenia puesta la etiqueta @autowired !!, que por cierto no se que significa

Answer (score 0):

¿ No te saca nada, si haces SOUT antes de realizar el insert tampoco ?. Quizas no estes mirando el registro de log adecuado.

Comment: no, no me arroja ningun error ni nada.